# Dispatch recursive generic function call based on array parameter type

Tags: c#

Writing a function which for a given type behaves differently depending on whether the parameter is an array of arbitrarily deep dimensions, or a non-array (value). For array types, the overload iterates over the array and recurses.

I would like the recursion to call the array parameter overload for recursive calls to sub-arrays. However instead the recursive call goes straight to the value type overload. I would prefer to avoid runtime based functionality such as introspection.

Using Visual Studio 2010 .Net 4 although would like to support .Net 3.5 as well.

```
namespace Quickie.StackOverflow.GenericMethodDispatch
{
    class TestGenericMethodDispatch
    {
        static private void GenericDereferenceArray<T>(T t)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("GenericDereferenceArray<T>(T t) got a {0} which thinks it's a {1}, {2}", typeof(T), t.GetType(), t));
        }

        static private void GenericDereferenceArray<T>(T[] t)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("GenericDereferenceArray<T>(T[] t) got a {0} which thinks it's a {1}", typeof(T[]), t.GetType()));
            foreach (T iter in t)
            {
                GenericDereferenceArray(iter);
            }
        }

        static public void TestGenericDereferenceArray()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("===TestGenericDereferenceArray()===");

            Console.WriteLine("====Dereference an int====");
            int i = 1;
            GenericDereferenceArray(i);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("====Dereference an int[]====");
            int[] ai = { 1 };
            GenericDereferenceArray(ai);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("====Dereference an int[][]====");
            int[][] aai = { new int[] { 2 } };
            GenericDereferenceArray(aai);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    } // Ends class TestGenericMethodDispatch
} // Ends namespace Quickie.StackOverflow.GenericMethodDispatch
```

Output:

> ===TestGenericDereferenceArray()===
>   ====Dereference a string====
>   GenericDereferenceArray(T t) got a System.String which thinks it's a System.String, foo
>
> ====Dereference an int====
>   GenericDereferenceArray(T t) got a System.Int32 which thinks it's a System.Int32, 1
>
> ====Dereference an int[]====
>   GenericDereferenceArray(T[] t) got a System.Int32[] which thinks it's a System.Int32[]
>   GenericDereferenceArray(T t) got a System.Int32 which thinks it's a System.Int32, 1
>
> ====Dereference an int[][]====
>   GenericDereferenceArray(T[] t) got a System.Int32[][] which thinks it's a System.Int32[][]
>   GenericDereferenceArray(T t) got a System.Int32[] which thinks it's a System.Int32[], System.Int32[]

Hoping the latter output would have been

> ====Dereference an int[][]====
>   GenericDereferenceArray(T[] t) got a System.Int32[][] which thinks it's a System.Int32[][]
>   GenericDereferenceArray(T[] t) got a System.Int32[] which thinks it's a System.Int32[]
>   GenericDereferenceArray(T t) got a System.Int32 which thinks it's a System.Int32, System.Int32

Answer (score 0):

Because `GenericDereferenceArray(iter)` calls `GenericDereferenceArray<T>(T t)` even though it's an array.  You could check for an array (or a more generic `IEnumerable` within `GenericDereferenceArray<T>(T t)`:

```
    static private void GenericDereferenceArray<T>(T t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("GenericDereferenceArray<T>(T t) got a {0} which thinks it's a {1}, {2}", typeof(T), t.GetType(), t));
        if (t is IEnumerable)
            foreach (var t2 in (IEnumerable)t)
            {
                GenericDereferenceArray(t2);
            }
    }
```

Comment: It's clear that "GenericDereferenceArray<T>(T t)" is being called from the output. That doesn't help me understand why, or whether there's a way around this that doesn't require this kind of casting. Casting to something which you know is valid smells wrong to me. Casting an element of a T[][] array to a T[] or IEnumerable<T> seems redundant.

Comment: Because when you call `GenericDereferenceArray(iter)` you're passing in an object rather than an _explicit_ array of objects.  Even though _technically_ it's an array, the compiler will wire it up to the T version.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an `int[][]` as an argument to a method that expects `T[]`, that makes `T` be of type `int[]`, which is what you see in the output. To make it behave like you want, you have to have special handling in your method for that situation.

Or, add another overload for `T[][]`.

Comment: Given that it doesn't make the match (for whatever reason), is there a way to use some extra dispatching or trampoline function which does recognise that T is an array, and make it jump back into the T[] overloaded version of the function, without writing explicit if statements or reflection ? Perhaps I should write one generic type argument as T and the other as X to make this more explicit. It won't make any difference to the output but separates out any suggestion that it's the re-use of T which is the issue.